# UIViewController not filling screen

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationController that pushes on another UIViewController.  In this UIViewController I am going to show a UITableView when in portrait mode and another view in landscape mode.

Therefore in my viewDidLoad I am creating UIView and then adding 2 ViewControllers to this. My problem is that when it loads up I get the following white margin at the top.
[image: example]

I think this is because of (in my Step 3 below ) the

```
CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
[[self view] setFrame:appFrame];
```

is not returning the full screen, minus the navigation bar. Is this right? If so how can I make it return the full size so there is no white margin?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Step 1 - Set up the tableDataView for vertical layout
TableDataViewController *tableController = [[TableDataViewController alloc] init];
self.tableDataViewController = tableController;
[tableController release];

// Step 2 - Set up the graphView for horizontal layout
GraphViewController *graphController = [[GraphViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"GraphViewController" bundle:nil];
self.graphViewController = graphController;
[graphController release];

// Step 3 - Get the screen size
CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
[[self view] setFrame:appFrame];

// Step 4 - Add the vertical view to the containerView
//        and then add the containerView to this controller
containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:appFrame] autorelease]; 
[[self view] addSubview:containerView];                     
[containerView addSubview:[tableDataViewController view]];

// Step 5 - Add to the active view so we can test for it later
activeView = [tableDataViewController view];    
 }
```

Many thanks

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an issue with your frame offsets. With the navigation bar enabled the rect you get in appFrame has a y offset of 44.f (the navigation bar's height) - check with NSLog and see if that's true.

Because you are setting the frame of a view that will be placed at the origin it should have x and y origins set to zero. You can do this in a safer manner by checking

```
CGFloat navHeight = navController.navigationBarHidden ? 0 :
    navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
```

In fact I think using the bounds property of [UIScreen mainScreen] may be a better overall solution. It will come with the origin and size set correctly and you shouldn't need to check the presence of the navigation bar.

Check what's going on:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(screenBounds));
CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(screenFrame));
```

Comment: When I do what you suggest above I get the following: Screenbounds {{0,0},{320,480}}, Screenframe {{0,20},{320,460}}.  So ideally I need to use the [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] to get the maximum size. However I do this and I still have a white margin beneath the navigation bar.  It's like it's totally ignoring it. Mike.

Comment: I have just been playing around with this and it appears it totally ignores what I set the **CGRect appFrame** to.  I just did CGRectMake(0,0,20,20) and there was no difference. The tableController and graphController are somehow behaving on their own.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things going on. Above all, `frame` describes a view's location **in its superview's coordinate system**.

`containerView` seems to be added as a subview of a custom view, and its coordinate system origins below the navigation bar, not the application frame.

You want to fill the custom view, so the frame of `containerView` should be something like

`CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height);`